# Discarding tautological premises in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a hypothesis in the local context, let's call it `H` which is of the form `true=true -> conclusion`. Which tactic can I use to discard the premise and retain only the conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This asserts the premise as a subgoal and then tries to prove both it, and the original goal with the conclusion of H prepended, using the trivial tactic.

```
lapply H; trivial.
```

Comment: Thanks. This can be used to do what I want, and it allows variations according to the case. When I tried this, 'trivial.' only solved one subgoal at a time, not both. As 'lapply' adds the premise as the second subgoal, '2:trivial.' can be used to get rid of it in order to keep working with the original goal.

Comment: Aside: I have never managed to make the syntax 2:TACTIC work. I always use ProofGeneral to interact with Coq - maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `specialize` tactic: http://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic35

`specialize (H (eq_refl true))`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following. Either of these works:

> assert (H2 : conclusion). apply H. reflexivity.
>
> assert (H2 : true->true). reflexivity. apply H in H2.

`assert (H2 := H (eq_refl true)).` also works. I would still like to know about cleaner solutions.